# In Ruby, why is a method invocation not able to be treated as a unit when "do" and "end" is used?

Tags: ruby, syntax, function, methods

The following question is related to the question "[Ruby Print Inject Do Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127836/ruby-print-inject-do-syntax)". My question is, can we insist on using `do` and `end` and make it work with `puts` or `p`?

This works:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

b = a.inject do |sum, x|
  sum + x
end
puts b   # prints out 10
```

so, is it correct to say, `inject` is an instance method of the Array object, and this instance method takes a block of code, and then returns a number.  If so, then it should be no different from calling a function or method and getting back a return value:

```
b = foo(3)
puts b
```

or

```
b = circle.getRadius()
puts b
```

In the above two cases, we can directly say

```
puts foo(3)
puts circle.getRadius()
```

so, there is no way to make it work directly by using the following 2 ways:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

puts a.inject do |sum, x|
  sum + x
end
```

but it gives

```
ch01q2.rb:7:in `inject': no block given (LocalJumpError)
        from ch01q2.rb:4:in `each'
        from ch01q2.rb:4:in `inject'
        from ch01q2.rb:4
```

grouping the method call using `( )` doesn't work either:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

puts (a.inject do |sum, x| 
        sum + x   
      end)
```

and this gives:

```
ch01q3.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected kDO_BLOCK, expecting ')'
puts (a.inject do |sum, x|
                 ^
ch01q3.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '='
puts (a.inject do |sum, x|
                          ^
ch01q3.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
      end)
         ^
```

finally, the following version works:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

puts a.inject { |sum, x|
    sum + x
}
```

but why doesn't the grouping of the method invocation using `( )` work in the earlier example?  What if a programmer insist that he uses `do` and `end`, can it be made to work?

Comment: `inject` is actually an instance method.

Comment: ah, that's right, a method invoked to touch the instance's values / properties should be an instance method.

Comment: thank you Matthew, corrected in question.

Comment: i dont' why you wrote such a huge, philosophical question when all that is at issue is really just a question of precedence

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the (unofficial) [ruby grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663027/ruby-grammar), we see that the contents of `(...)` in `puts (...)` must be `CALL_ARGS`, which don't directly reduce to `STMT`. However, they can reduce to `'(' COMPSTMT ')'`. By including an extra set of parentheses, you can use `do ... end`.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

puts ((a.inject do |sum, x| 
         sum + x   
       end))
```

Comment: it does work.  it may come off as strange to me at first as Ruby's parenthesis is sometimes optional.  And also, have 2 sets of `( )` may come off as, if one pair doesn't work, add an extra pair.

Answer (score 7):

The issue here isn't just your parentheses: it's primarily the space *after* `puts` *before* the parentheses.

With the code

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

puts (a.inject do |sum, x|
             sum + x
                    end)
```

We get the syntax errors you listed in the question.

If you drop the space after `puts`,

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

puts(a.inject do |sum, x|
             sum + x
                    end)
```

prints out `10` as expected.

Finally, using `puts ((a.inject...` with the space and double parentheses *also* prints out `10`, but running that through `ruby -cw XXX.rb` tells us:

> `a.rb:5: warning: (...) interpreted as grouped expression`
>
> `Syntax OK`

`ruby -cw` is used to **C**heck the syntax with full **W**arnings turned on.  When `-cw` is on, you will be warned about dubious parentheses and grouping.  The error I'm more used to seeing is "don't put space before argument parentheses" -- so don't do that either!

Lastly, the reason `a.inject do` fails without parentheses but `a.inject {` works, is that braces have a higher precedence than `do`/`end`.  As a very *rough* guideline, you could say that `p a.map { foo }` is equivalent to `p(a.map do foo end)`; and `p a.map do foo end` is equivalent to `(p a.map) do foo end`, which of course does not take a block argument.

See also the [Ruby quick reference on blocks](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#31) (particularly the last two lines):

> ### Blocks, Closures, and Procs
>
> #### Blocks/Closures
>
> - blocks must follow a method invocation:
>
> `invocation do ... end`
>
> `invocation { ... }`
>
> - Blocks remember their variable context, and are full closures.
> - Blocks are invoked via yield and may be passed arguments.
> - Brace form has higher precedence and will bind to the last parameter if invocation made w/o parens.
> - do/end form has lower precedence and will bind to the invocation even without parens.