# Block definition - difference between braces and do-end?

Tags: ruby, block

can anybody explain why the following code aborts with an error

```
irb(main):186:0> print ((1..10).collect do |x| x**2 end)
SyntaxError: (irb):186: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block,
expecting ')'
print ((1..10).collect do |x| x**2 end)
                         ^
(irb):186: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
print ((1..10).collect do |x| x**2 end)
                                      ^
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

whereas following code with the same functionality works as expected ?

```
irb(main):187:0> print ((1..10).collect { |x| x**2 })
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]=> nil
```

I did believed curly-braces "{ }" can substitute "do end" arbitrarily at block
definition.

I know I can "fix" the first call by omitting a space between print
method and the first parenthesis, but I'm interested in an explanation
*why* it behaves different.

Comment: See [similar question premise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122380/using-do-block-vs-brackets) also.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Ruby Block Syntax Error](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6854283/), [Code block passed to `each` works with brackets but not with `do`-`end` (ruby)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6718340/), [Ruby multiline block without `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3680097/), [Using `do` block vs brackets `{}`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2122380/), [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/533008/) and [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/420147/).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: `blocks` is an ambiguous tag that does not help get this question answered. There are fewer than 200 questions tagged with `blocks` and only a handful address Ruby blocks.

Comment: @coreyward: There are 71 questions tagged ruby and block, and 56 tagged ruby and blockS (and only one of those overlap).

Answer (score 13):

The difference is precedence:

```
# Equivalent to puts( (1..10).map { |i| i*2 } )
> puts (1..10).map { |i| i*2 }
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
 => nil 

# Equivalent to puts( (1..10).map ) { |i| i*2 }
> puts (1..10).map do |i| i*2 end
#<Enumerator:0x928f24>
 => nil
```

In the first case, the block is passed to `map`, and everything works properly.
In the second case, the block is passed to `puts`, which doesn't do anything with it. `map` doesn't receive a block and just returns an enumerator.

As for the syntax error, if you remove the space between `print` and `(` everything works ;)

The difference is whether ruby is treating your parentheses as method argument delimiters, or whether it's a generic statement grouping. I'm not sure of the exact difference there but it's subtle and annoying

Comment: Your second example is different from the one that is in the question.

Comment: Yes it's just a demonstration of precedence, not a direct fix. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Answer (score 0):

There is an *ultimate* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762791/in-ruby-why-is-a-method-invocation-not-able-to-be-treated-as-a-unit-when-do-an/2762847#2762847) already on SO.

Unfortunately this is definitely **not** a good demonstration of least surprise philosophy behind Ruby.