# Use 'puts' with block accepting method over multiple lines

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have the following (working) pseudo-code:

```
puts results.fields.inject('') { |string, key|
  lengths[key] = calculate_length(key)
  string << format(key)
}
```

Following the ruby-style-guide I should

- Omit parentheses for 'keyword methods', i.e. `puts`, (which would create `})` or `end)` anyway)
- Use `do...end` for multi-line blocks

However, when replacing `{...}` with `do...end` it raises

```
undefined method `' for :title:Symbol (NoMethodError)
```

Therefore, is it possible to refactor this code without violenting the guideline?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in precedence between `{}` and `do end`

If you use `do end` the block is associated with the `puts` statement, whereas the braces are associated with the `results.field.inject('')`

If you want to use `do end` then you have to remove the ambiguity of association by parentheses.  It's one of those "gotchas" where the guidelines are recognized as guidelines, not absolute rules.

See also this answer...

[In Ruby, why is a method invocation not able to be treated as a unit when "do" and "end" is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762791/in-ruby-why-is-a-method-invocation-not-able-to-be-treated-as-a-unit-when-do-a/2762847#2762847)